# How to omit string change when two vowels are next to eachother

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I am trying to write a code that makes use of the language Oppengloppish by adding "opp" before each vowel in an English word. This is the code that I currently have written but I am having trouble with one thing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

bool is_vowel(char c)
{
    return c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u';
}
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    const string vowel_postfix = "opp";
    string word, oword;
    cin >> word;
    auto vowel_count = count_if(word.begin(), word.end(), is_vowel);
    oword.reserve(word.length() + vowel_count * 2);
    for (char c : word) {
        oword.push_back(c);
        if (is_vowel(c))
            oword.insert(oword.length() -1, vowel_postfix);
    }
    cout << oword << std::endl;
}
```

I would like to try to omit "opp" from being added when there is a grouping of vowels but still have it added to only the first vowel.

Example: score-> scopporoppe

Expected behavior: team-> toppeam
Current behavior: team-> toppeoppam

Comment: Have the program remember that the last character was a vowel. Test that memory at each new vowel and clear it when a consonant is found.

Comment: "toppeam" is adding "opp" before a vowel, but "scooppreopp" seems to be adding "opp" **after** vowels.  Is this really what you want?

Comment: Warning: Looks like you're missing a few includes, `string` and `iostream` specifically.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear where you want to add the word (before or after the first vowel in the vowels group). In any case, what you are looking for is the **transition from a consonant to a vowel**. You need to remember the previous letter and see if it is a consonant and if the current letter is a vowel. The following code adds the word before the first vowel ([demo](https://www.ideone.com/rDN1WW)):

```
char prev = 'b'; // must be initialized to an arbitrary consonant, otherwise if the first letter is a vowel, it won't be detected.
for (char c : word)
{
  if (!is_vowel(prev) && is_vowel(c))
    oword += "opp"; // transition detected
  oword += prev = c;
}
```

A less intuitive solution would be to test the last letter added to the output word:

```
for (char c : word)
{
  if (is_vowel(c) && (oword.empty() || !is_vowel(oword.back())))
    oword += "opp";
  oword += c;
}
```

Note that you should also test capital letters.

Answer (score 0):

You could:

- walk the input string.
- creating an output string along the way.
- keeping count if the previous character was a vowel or not.
- in case the previous character was not a vowel, and the current one is, add `oop` to the output string.
- always add the current character to the output string.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/G37Pjf3n1)

```cpp
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

std::string insert_opp(std::string_view text) {
    auto is_vowel = [](char c) {
        static std::string_view vowels{ "aeiouAEIOU" };
        return vowels.contains(c);
    };
    std::string ret{};
    bool is_vowel_previous_c{ false };
    for (auto c : text) {
        auto is_vowel_c{ is_vowel(c) };
        if (!is_vowel_previous_c && is_vowel_c) {
            ret += "oop";
        }
        ret += c;
        is_vowel_previous_c = is_vowel_c;
    }
    return ret;
}

int main() {
    for (auto& text : { "team", "score", "aeiou", "" }) {
        fmt::print("'{}' -> '{}'\n", text, insert_opp(text));
    }
}

// Outputs:
//
// 'team' -> 'toopeam'
// 'score' -> 'scooporoope'
// 'aeiou' -> 'oopaeiou'
// '' -> ''
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem can easily be solved using a regex replacement. First create a regex that captures 1 or more consecutive vowels:

```
std::regex vowels{"([aeiou]+)"};
```

and then replace all occurrences of this pattern with `"opp"` followed by the pattern itself (which is denoted by `$1`):

```
auto oword = std::regex_replace(word, vowels, "opp$1");
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7Pnddefr9).